# Why is the onclick not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the onclick not calling my javascript function?

It will work if I just call the function testF() from a javascript function.

Code:

```
<img src="s/256base-open-over.png" onclick="testF();">Dr. No. (1962)</a>



function testF() {
    console.log("logTest");
    alert("test");
}
```

Here is the whole page:

Your correct on that the script is not loading first. But if I make the JSPlayer load first then it does not show up were I want it located in the page which is after the header jpg and before the drop down menu.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Movie List</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="Qa7RBzf9bd+ojVxVkkgEDslXu/QYZVRmhb+PGwNDJhtx/QB0x6hgvQ==";
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="s/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>

<style>
.Three-Dee{
font-family: Courier, monospace;
line-height: 1em;
color: #e81ee8;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 80px;
text-shadow:0px 0px 0 rgb(88,-114,88),1px 0px 0 rgb(72,-130,72),2px 0px 0 rgb(57,-145,57),3px 0px 0 rgb(41,-161,41),4px 0px 0 rgb(26,-176,26),5px 0px 0 rgb(10,-192,10),6px 0px 0 rgb(-5,-207,-5),7px 0px 0 rgb(-21,-223,-21),8px 0px 0 rgb(-36,-238,-36),9px 0px 0 rgb(-52,-254,-52),10px 0px 0 rgb(-67,-269,-67),11px 0px 0 rgb(-83,-285,-83),12px 0px 0 rgb(-98,-300,-98),13px 0px 0 rgb(-114,-316,-114), 14px 0px 0 rgb(-129,-331,-129),15px 0px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),15px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 0px 14px rgba(0,0,0,.2);}

.Three-DeeTwo{
font-family: Courier, monospace;
line-height: 1em;
color: #1a071a;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 15px;
text-shadow:0px 0px 0 rgb(10,-9,10),1px 0px 0 rgb(-7,-26,-7),2px 0px 0 rgb(-23,-42,-23), 3px 0px 0 rgb(-39,-58,-39),4px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0),4px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);}
</style>    

</head>
<body style="background-color:#E2EBEB">
<center>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="120" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</center>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'j1.jpg';
    </script>
<hr>
<center>
<div id="test" class="auto-style1">Loading the player...</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">

function setM(value) {
//  {file: "valley.mp4",label: "144p"}
alert(value);
     jwplayer("test").setup({
      playlist: [{
        image: "ticket.jpg",
        sources: [
        {file: value,label: "144p"}
        ]
      }]
    });
}

setM("valley.mp4");

function testF() {
    console.log("logTest");
    alert("test");
}

    function sendName(name) {
      alert(name);
    }
   </script>
</center>

<center>
    <div class="Three-Dee">Movie List</div>
</center>

<center>
    <h5>Click Menu Below!</h5>
</center>

<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="switchbox"><label onclick="" class="switch" for="css3menu-switcher"></label>   
    <li class="topfirst"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over.png" onclick="setM("00223.144p.mp4");" />Dr. No. (1962)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over.png" alt=""/>From Russia With Love (1963)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over2.png" alt=""/>Goldfinger (1964)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over3.png" alt=""/>Thuderball (1965)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over5.png" alt=""/>You Only Live Twice (1967)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over6.png" alt=""/>On Her Majesty's Secret Service (1969)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over7.png" alt=""/>Diamonds Are Forever (1971)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over8.png" alt=""/>Live and Let Die (1973)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over9.png" alt=""/>The Man with the Golden Gun (1974)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over10.png" alt=""/>The Spy Who Loved Me (1977)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over11.png" alt=""/>Moonraker (1979)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over12.png" alt=""/>For Your Eyes Only (1981)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over13.png" alt=""/>Octopussy (1983)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over14.png" alt=""/>A View To A Kill (1985)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over15.png" alt=""/>The Living Daylights (1987)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over16.png" alt=""/>Licence to Kill (1989)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over17.png" alt=""/>Goldeney (1995)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over18.png" alt=""/>Tomorrow Never Dies (1997)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over19.png" alt=""/>The World is Not Enough (1999)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over20.png" alt=""/>Die Another Day (2002)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over21.png" alt=""/>Casino Royal (2006)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over22.png" alt=""/>Quantum of Solace (2008)</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
    <img src="s/256base-open-over23.png" alt=""/>Skyfall (2012)</a></li>
</ul><p class="_css3m"><a href="http://css3menu.com/">vertical menu css</a> by Css3Menu.com</p>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->

<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Main code for JSPlayer

```
function setM(value) {
//  {file: "valley.mp4",label: "144p"}
alert(value);
     jwplayer("test").setup({
      playlist: [{
        image: "ticket.jpg",
        sources: [
        {file: value,label: "144p"}
        ]
      }]
    });
}

setM("valley.mp4");
```

The above is the code that sets the player that will play the videos. JS player is the name. The code is located in the body of the html right were I want the player to be located. If you click on the menu and then click on a movie name it will change the player so that the player will play this particular movie.

Problem: What I have not been able to do is to be able to click on a menu link an then be able to play that particular movie. This is what I would like it to be. A friend gave me a test copy of JS player but I am thinking that it might be better to use a Canvas to play the video because You can place a canvas in this specific location and then use JavaScript to play a video.

I think that because the code for the JSPlayer is actual in the body of the html might be the problem???? Not completely certain.

[image]

Comment: this is actually working

Comment: Your code is not in a `<script>` element... please post a **complete** example.

Comment: Mmh, for some reason your actual code is quite different. Have a look at `onclick="setM("00223.144p.mp4");"`. Do you notice anything strange with the quotation marks? Hint: The HTML parser sees this as `onclick="setM(" 00223.144p.mp4");"=""`. Make a right click on the image -> inspect element and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your opening tag is `<img>`, but your closing tag is `</a>`: those do not match.

Try this:

```
<img src="s/256base-open-over.png" onclick="testF();"/>Dr. No. (1962)
```

(The `<img>` tag is self-closing.)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/u0r3ywz7/)

However, that shouldn't stop the execution of the JavaScript, so make sure that your JavaScript is located somewhere that gives the `testF()` function global scope and that your JavaScript loads before your page does.

It also may be that you forgot to wrap your code in `<script>` tags: you can't just throw JavaScript in HTML and expect it to work.

```
<script>
    function testF() {
        console.log("logTest");
        alert("test");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It is in a script tag. It is located in the <head> section which will load the script first.

Comment: No, I still cannot get it to call that method.

Comment: @DougHauf: If it doesn't work, why did you accept this answer?

Comment: @DougHauf I'd love to help, but you haven't given us many details here: don't accept my answer if it didn't solve your problem.